# How to return all properties in the model class from toString() method

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a simple crud app in android studio. I've implemented the Insert and View parts. I have created a list view to view items. But only display only one property in one record. I want to get all properties of a record to list view. I am a beginner in android development. Please tell me how to do it. Thank you. :)

first, I call a method in the model class

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.courseDescription;
    }
```

In this method, I can only return one property only. I need to return all properties in string data type.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Now that you have an answer to your question, you might want to edit your question to remove the extraneous information.  For example, this has nothing to do with ormlite, sqlite, or crud right?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code :

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course{" +
                "courseId=" + courseId +
                ", courseName='" + courseName + '\'' +
                ", courseDuration='" + courseDuration + '\'' +
                ", courseDescription='" + courseDescription + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```